# R: Loop Function Across Columns and Create New (named) Columns for Each Function Output

Tags: r, function, for-loop, multiple-columns, autocorrelation

I am trying to:

1. generate Moran's I Estimates and P-Values for variables in columns 11:27 of the @data portion of a SpatialPointsDataFrame, for a given year of data (below is 2016)
2. repeat (1) for all years of data, and bind these together: resulting in a complete SpatialPointsDataFrame which has 2 columns containing these Moran's measures named "LM_(variable)" and "LM(p)_(variable)" for each of the original variables.

I have defined a function to perform the first Moran's estimate for a single year subset but can't figure out how to add these as appropriately named columns to the dataframe OR loop these. See (incorrect) code below:

```
OA.2016 <- OA.Merge.1[OA.Merge.1$Year==2016, ]

LM.1 <- function(i){

  LM.i <- localmoran(x = i, listw = nb2listw(neighbours.queen.2016, style = "W", zero.policy=TRUE), zero.policy=TRUE)
  colnames(LM.i) <- c("Estimate","Standard Error","Variance","Z-Score","P-Value")

  LM.i <- LM.i[, c(1)]
  LM.i <- as.data.frame(LM.i)

  OA.2016@data <- cbind(OA.2016@data,LM.i)

}
```

I then try to apply this (and a similar function for the p-value) in a loop:

```
for(i in OA.2016@data[11:27]){
  OA.2016[[paste("LM_", i,sep="")]]<-LM.1(OA.2016[[i]])
  OA.2016[[paste("LM(p)_", i,sep="")]]<-LM.2(OA.2016[[i]])
}
```

Ideally all stages could be combined so that the input is a SpatialPolgonsDataFrame with unit Year//Census-Tract and the output is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with the same unit and rows, but many additional named columns containing correct Moran's estimates, calculated ONLY for Census Tracts in the specific year (hence the need to specify the variables on a year subset, then loop over years and re-combine).

ANY help on this would be amazing! Thanks.